# Android cart button not working with database

Tags: java, android

I really need help while whenever I press cart button to add food to basket app stop working and can't submit my assignment when cart button doesn't work. I use Firebase which is working and DB browser for SQLite. I triple - quatrocheck the names in databases with the names in code and still I don't know why it doesn't work. Would appreciate any help.

error in picture (LogCat): https://ibb.co/n4bMWb

Code of Databases.

```js
package com.example.onix.AndroEat.Database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Order;


public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME="Eat.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME,null, DB_VER);
    }

    public List<Order> getCarts()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect={"ID","ProductName","ProductId","Quantity","Price",};
        String sqlTable="OrderDetail";

        qb.setTables(sqlTable);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);

        final List<Order> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                result.add(new Order(
                        c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductId")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ProductName")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Quantity")),
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Price"))
                        ));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void addToCart(Order order) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice());
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void cleanCart()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM OrderDetail");
        db.execSQL(query);
    }


    public int getCountCart() {
        int count=0;

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderDetail");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
           do{
               count = cursor.getInt(0);
           }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void updateCart(Order order) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("UPDATE OrderDetail SET Quantity= %s WHERE ID = %d",order.getQuantity(),order.getID());
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

Code of FoodDetail:

```js
package com.example.onix.AndroEat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab;
import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Common.Common;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.stepstone.apprating.AppRatingDialog;
import com.stepstone.apprating.listener.RatingDialogListener;

import java.util.Arrays;

import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Food;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Order;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Model.Rating;
import com.example.onix.AndroEat.Database.Database;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class FoodDetail extends AppCompatActivity implements RatingDialogListener {

    TextView food_name,food_price,food_description;
    ImageView food_image;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    FloatingActionButton btnRating;
    CounterFab btnCart;
    ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
    RatingBar ratingBar;

    String foodId="";

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference foods;
    DatabaseReference ratingTbl;

    Food currentFood;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/restaurant_font.otf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_detail);

        //Firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        foods = database.getReference("Foods");
        ratingTbl = database.getReference("Rating");

        //Init view
        numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
        btnCart = (CounterFab) findViewById(R.id.btnCart);
        btnRating = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_rating);
        ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showRatingDialog();
            }
        });

        btnCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Database(getBaseContext()).addToCart(new Order(
                        foodId,
                        currentFood.getName(),
                        numberButton.getNumber(),
                        currentFood.getPrice()
                ));

                Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnCart.setCount(new Database(this).getCountCart());

        food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description);
        food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        food_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExpandedAppbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);

        //Get Food Id from Intent
        if(getIntent() != null)
            foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
        if(!foodId.isEmpty())
        {
            if(Common.isConnectedToInterner(getBaseContext()))
            {
                getDetailFood(foodId);
                getRatingFood(foodId);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Please check your connection !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void getRatingFood(String foodId) {

        com.google.firebase.database.Query foodRating = ratingTbl.orderByChild("foodId").equalTo(foodId);

        foodRating.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            int count=0,sum=0;
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
               {
                   Rating item = postSnapshot.getValue(Rating.class);
                   sum+=Integer.parseInt(item.getRateValue());
                   count++;
               }
               if(count != 0)
               {
                   float average = sum/count;
                   ratingBar.setRating(average);
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void showRatingDialog() {
        new AppRatingDialog.Builder()
                .setPositiveButtonText("Submit")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                .setNoteDescriptions(Arrays.asList("Very Bad","Not Good","Quite Ok","Very Good","Excellent"))
                .setDefaultRating(1)
                .setTitle("Rate this food")
                .setDescription("Please select some stars and give your feedback")
                .setTitleTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .setDescriptionTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .setHint("Please write your comment here...")
                .setHintTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
                .setCommentTextColor(android.R.color.white)
                .setCommentBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                .setWindowAnimation(R.style.RatingDialogFadeAnim)
                .create(FoodDetail.this)
                .show();
    }

    private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {
        foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentFood = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);

                //Set Image
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(currentFood.getImage())
                        .into(food_image);

                collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(currentFood.getName());

                food_price.setText(currentFood.getPrice());

                food_name.setText(currentFood.getName());

                food_description.setText(currentFood.getDescription());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int value, String comments) {
        //Get Rating and upload to firebase
        final Rating rating = new Rating(Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                foodId,
                String.valueOf(value),
                comments);
        ratingTbl.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).exists())
                {
                    //Remove old value (you can delete or let it be - useless function :D)
                    ratingTbl.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).removeValue();
                    //Update new value
                    ratingTbl.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).setValue(rating);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Update new value
                    ratingTbl.child(Common.currentUser.getPhone()).setValue(rating);
                }
                Toast.makeText(FoodDetail.this, "Thank you for submit rating !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {

    }
}
```

Will post more code IF needed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The full error from the logca twould be useful.

Comment: Its better to post code as String but not Picture. Sometimes small modifications are required and someone can copy and paste and edit some code for you when giving an answer!

Comment: Oki guys sorry for causing problem will make both in 2-3 minutes :)

Comment: Done updated problem! Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"," should be removed after price in the above code. Below is the rite code

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                    order.getProductId(),
                    order.getProductName(),
                    order.getQuantity(),
                    order.getPrice());
```

Also remove "," from below code above

```
String[] sqlSelect={"ID","ProductName","ProductId","Quantity","Price"};
```

Comment: wow thank you now everything is working the only thing is not working is the calculate the price. for example when i add more than 1 item it crash.

Comment: Thank you i appreciate it :) Have a nice day i wil ltry and fix the total price now and am done!

Comment: Actually with your updated answer is working.. Hero <3

Comment: Good to know. It was helpfull. Also upvote answer if possible for other to see the answer

Comment: Yeah it was helpful now i am trying to make payment with paypal and that's it.  I already do it but i am 9 rep and need to go 15 to vote :( sorry i tick it. Have a nice day :)